# Magento external theme installation trouble

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm trying to install a Magento theme.I am trying to install it by coping theme's app,skin and js folder into magento's app,js and skin folder.Theme works okay except the home page.

In homepage's content section i have add this:

```
<div>
    {{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/my_template.phtml"}}
</div>
```

which loads theme's template and sets its design but in my case it doesn't apply the template, What i lack here?
Other Pages like About us,Contact us are working according to theme but not homepage..
In the other pages which are working,content written in content section is directly a data,where in homepage it is a reference to a template called "my_template.phtml".. 
help me guys!

Comment: Here on **Stack Overflow**, all questions must be rich..

Comment: What more information is required?

Comment: Just make a question understandable to the people that are trying to guess, mostly the title, and it'll be okay..

Comment: I believe its straight forward question..suggest me more if its still blurred or anything..i'll be more than happy to receive it..i am bit new